# esbuild initial total size larger than what source-map-explorer shows (ionic standalone/angular)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, esbuild

I upgraded to Angular 17 with esbuild and ionic standalone components. (using the `@angular-devkit/build-angular:application` builder).
I removed any reference to IonicModule and only import from `@ionic/angular/standalone`.

When i build my app, i get an initial total of ~2mb the larges chunk being 811kb (ionic). Before migration to esbuild and ionic standalone the total was ~1.3mb.
I'm really confused... When I explore the source maps, the combined total is ~1mb, but why does the build output say 2mb?

```
Initial Chunk Files              | Names                |  Raw Size | Estimated Transfer Size
chunk-EPET7CDY.js                | -                    | 819.14 kB |                99.05 kB
chunk-X7NYWEYA.js                | -                    | 320.18 kB |                82.81 kB
chunk-CBZTRNPS.js                | -                    | 310.68 kB |                81.88 kB
main-MHHDKQ2E.js                 | main                 | 238.68 kB |                67.87 kB
chunk-B4R2VYPJ.js                | -                    | 151.02 kB |                41.59 kB
chunk-5LI6OJTD.js                | -                    |  38.12 kB |                10.50 kB
chunk-L7C2ILS5.js                | -                    |  35.03 kB |                11.52 kB
polyfills-ROJ3GJHA.js            | polyfills            |  32.74 kB |                10.64 kB
styles-MRZBGAV3.css              | styles               |  27.11 kB |                 4.14 kB
chunk-IMWMSQZF.js                | -                    |  23.11 kB |                 7.45 kB
chunk-QL65RZZY.js                | -                    |  16.33 kB |                 5.04 kB
chunk-3YOUIAQ4.js                | -                    |  11.03 kB |                 3.97 kB
chunk-S5W54PMN.js                | -                    |   9.92 kB |                 2.59 kB
chunk-X3WD76IK.js                | -                    |   9.30 kB |                 3.62 kB
chunk-44IUEHHX.js                | -                    |   5.72 kB |                 2.13 kB
chunk-K5E2RLRT.js                | -                    |   3.33 kB |                 1.24 kB
chunk-6OAZX7JI.js                | -                    |   1.55 kB |               714 bytes
chunk-5OWHKVSO.js                | -                    |   1.45 kB |               664 bytes
chunk-TKTPQQUO.js                | -                    |   1.44 kB |               596 bytes
chunk-4KBQPFIY.js                | -                    |   1.08 kB |               563 bytes
chunk-F4PI7WOR.js                | -                    |   1.04 kB |               511 bytes
chunk-RFR4477V.js                | -                    | 989 bytes |               989 bytes
chunk-5NXBGC7U.js                | -                    | 951 bytes |               951 bytes
chunk-6OAZAW2S.js                | -                    | 721 bytes |               721 bytes
chunk-A5ZPVNR2.js                | -                    | 664 bytes |               664 bytes
chunk-ILNDS6YC.js                | -                    | 584 bytes |               584 bytes
chunk-FLF7PI3E.js                | -                    | 515 bytes |               515 bytes
chunk-OWT5PGYW.js                | -                    | 381 bytes |               381 bytes
chunk-CBTCPHC5.js                | -                    | 146 bytes |               146 bytes
chunk-7T7YRGPO.js                | -                    | 142 bytes |               142 bytes

                                 | Initial Total        |   2.01 MB |               444.00 kB
```

source-map-explorer:
[image: source-map-explorer]

esbuild analyzer (please note, this includes server bundles (*.mjs) as well):
[image: esbuild analyzer]

source-